# Karma/Jasmine unit test with JSPM 404 on my JSPM packages

Tags: ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine, jspm, babeljs

I am trying to make JSPM / Karma / Babel / Jasmine all work together. But I am getting the error when running karma start

```
15 04 2016 17:34:02.428:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
15 04 2016 17:34:02.434:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
15 04 2016 17:34:03.353:INFO [Chrome 49.0.2623 (Mac OS X 10.11.3)]: Connected on socket /#BSCbuviA4_LADHmaAAAA with id 80043999
15 04 2016 17:34:04.212:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/aurelia-dependency-injection.js
15 04 2016 17:34:04.213:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/aurelia-router.js
Chrome 49.0.2623 (Mac OS X 10.11.3) ERROR
  Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading /Users/allen/dev/work/Web/aurelia-dependency-injection.js
    Error loading /Users/allen/dev/work/Web/wwwroot/src/app.js
```

My Folder Structure:

```
> Web
  karma.conf.js
  -> node_modules
  -> test
    --> unit
  -> wwwroot
    --> src (all my js)
    --> jspm_packages
    config.js
```

My Karam.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jspm', 'jasmine'],

    jspm: {
      // Edit this to your needs
      loadFiles: ['test/unit/setup.js', 'test/unit/**/*.js'],
      serveFiles: ['wwwroot/src/**/*.js'],
      paths: {
        '*': '*',
        'github:*': 'jspm_packages/github/*',
        'npm:*': 'jspm_packages/npm/*',
      },
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [],
    proxies: {
      '/base/jspm_packages/': '/base/wwwroot/jspm_packages/',
    },

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'test/**/*.js': ['babel'],
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
    },

    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: 'inline',
        presets: ['es2015-loose', 'stage-1'],
        plugins: [
          'syntax-flow',
          'transform-decorators-legacy',
          'transform-flow-strip-types',
        ],
      },
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,
  });
};
```

My app.js has these imports:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';
import { Navscroll } from '../src/modules/scroll-anim.js'
```

I am not sure if my proxy is setup right or not or what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading /Users/allen/dev/work/Web/aurelia-dependency-injection.js
Error loading /Users/allen/dev/work/Web/wwwroot/src/app.js
```

This is your first problem. It's not XHRing to your proxy. Instead it's trying to use a path url. This will definitely fail as an XHR can only do HTTP as far as I have ever seen. You need the protocol://host:port/path format.

Try going to `http://localhost:9876/src/app.js`  and see what shows up in your browser. (Might not need to include `/src/` `app.js` might be served from root.)

You must be loading the `app.js` file incorrectly somewhere. Please include the places you load `app.js`.